# Use flatmap with grouped observables

Tags: rx-java, rx-java3

I am new in RxJava and trying to understand it. I have the following source:

```
Observable<Employee> obs = Observable.just(
    new Employee(101, "Jim", 68_000, 4.2),
    new Employee(123, "Bill", 194_000, 6.7));  

obs.groupBy(e -> e.getRating())
                .flatMap(e-> {
                    return Observable.fromIterable(
                        Arrays.asList(e.getKey())
                    );
                })
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This prints the key which is the ratings but I can't print the values.
Is it possible using `flatMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupBy` returns an `Observable` that emits a `GroupedObservable` for each unique key. A `GroupedObservable` is really just an `Observable` with the addition of the `getKey` method, so you can identify which key that `GroupedObservable` is associated with. So, if you want to emit each value in each `GroupedObservable`, just pass the whole thing directly to the `flatMap` call:

```
Observable<Employee> obs = Observable.just(
    new Employee(101, "Jim", 68_000, 4.2),
    new Employee(123, "Bill", 194_000, 6.7));  

obs.groupBy(e -> e.getRating())
    .flatMap(e -> e)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: So inside the `flatMap` I don't have access to the value associated with the key?

Comment: @Jim Not if you don't have a reason to. What output are you expecting to see?

Comment: @Jim Oh, I think misread your question initially. The Observable that is passed into the `flatMap` contains all the values associated with the key, so you do have access to them.

Comment: But how? I don't see any method that when called on `e` inside the `flatMap` that gives me the values. E.g. if I wanted to append to each value something how would I do this?

Comment: @Jim `.flatMap(e -> e).map(employee -> /* append something here */)`

Comment: The above assumes you are actually transforming the object into a new type. If you're just changing the properties of the existing `Employee` object, use `doOnNext` instead of `map`.

Comment: So `flatMap` just takes each GroupObservable and merges them into one on which I can apply the `map`? That `.flatMap(e -> e)` as a notation is confusing to me that I am new in RxJava

Comment: @Jim yes, that is exactly what the `flatMap` call is doing. You start with `Observable<GroupedObservable<Employee>>`, and the `flatMap` flattens it into `Observable<Employee>`

Comment: Would it be possible to convert it to something that is a reduction of `Employee`? E.g. `Observable<Employee.name>` or it has to be a second step via a `map`?

Comment: @Jim You would have to do it in a map operator.